How to do smooth movement in JS Graphics on CodeHS
How do I do smooth movement in JS Graphics on CodeHS. Everything I see when I try to Google it is for when you're doing JS with HTML.
Here's my current code
let centerX = getWidth()/2;
let centerY = getHeight()/2;
let sqr;

function start(){
    createSquare();
    keyDownMethod(move);
}

function createSquare(){
    sqr = new Rectangle(50,50);
    sqr.setPosition(centerX-50/2,centerY-50/2)
    add(sqr);
}

function move(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('W') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        sqr.move(0,-5);
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('S') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        sqr.move(0,5);
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('A') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        sqr.move(-5,0);
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('D') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        sqr.move(5,0);
    }
}

At first I tried putting a move 1 in a for loop but it still basically just snaps to a position. I also tried doing that but with setTimeout but instead of waiting for the amount of milliseconds I put each time it loops it just waits and then does the loop the set amount of times even though the set time out is inside of the loop.

You can add a setTimer() call in your start() function that calls a function that changes your squares position. Then have your keyboard function just set values for how much to add to the current x and y position of your square.
I also added a key up function, so the square only moves while you are holding a key down.
let centerX = getWidth()/2;
let centerY = getHeight()/2;
let sqr;
const moveIncrement = 2  // Larger number will move faster but jumpier
let xIncrement = 0
let yIncrement = 0

function start(){
    createSquare();
    keyDownMethod(keyDown);
    keyUpMethod(keyUp);
}

function createSquare(){
    sqr = new Rectangle(50,50);
    sqr.setPosition(centerX-50/2,centerY-50/2)
    add(sqr);
    
    setTimer(update, 16);
}

function keyDown(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('W') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        yIncrement = -moveIncrement;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('S') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        yIncrement = moveIncrement;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('A') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        xIncrement = -moveIncrement;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('D') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        xIncrement = moveIncrement;
    }
}
function keyUp(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('W') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        yIncrement = 0;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('S') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        yIncrement = 0;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('A') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        xIncrement = 0;
    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('D') || e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        xIncrement = 0;
    }
}
function update() {
    sqr.move(xIncrement, yIncrement);
}


It only moves when the key is down without the keyUp function though?

No.
Paste the code into CodeHS and try it. Comment out or delete the keyUpMethod(keyUp) call and see for yourself.
